# How to Program respond in Oracle REST Data Services

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am using Oracle rest data service. So I need to program a respond to a particular request. For an example,

I get a request in application Express ORDS,

```
request_body BLOB:= :body;
```

Now I need to create a respond for this request. Like,

```
respond('application express ok'); // this sends to the client
```

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also provide document type and status code (and any other headers you can think of.

Example:
JSON:

```
begin
   owa_util.status_line (200, '', false);
   owa_util.mime_header ('application/json', true);
   htp.prn ('{"status":"everything is a ok"}');
end;
```

Text:

```
begin
   owa_util.status_line (200, '', false);
   owa_util.mime_header ('text/plain', true);
   htp.prn ('everything is a ok');
end;
```

And a bit bigger example using headers:

```
declare
   l_response   varchar2 (32767);
begin
   l_response := '<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Response</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Thank you for submitting</h2>
</body>
</html>';
   owa_util.status_line (200, '', false);
   htp.p ('Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"');
   htp.p ('Content-length: ' || trim (to_char (length (l_response), '999999999999999999')));
   owa_util.http_header_close;
   htp.prn (l_response);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, This can be done this way,

```
begin
htp.p('your textual content as respond body');
end
```

Using above syntax the respond body can be created.